# MVC5 Windows Authentication w/ Custom User Table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I'm tasked with creating Intranet site with Windows Username validated through a database, not AD.

The problem I'm facing is that MVC5 is authenticating all Windows user.

So,I tried this:

```
//Global.asax
protected void Application_AuthorizeRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   {
      var user = User.Identity.Name;
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(user))
      {
         using (var db = new dbDbContext())
         {
             if (!db.Users.Any(x => x.Username.ToLower() == user.ToLower()))
             {
                this.Response.StatusCode = 401;
             }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

So what happens here is the User is prompted to give their credentials if they aren't in the Users table. The only problem is that if they hit cancel they go to the Page anyway!

Comment: Return a 403 Forbidden instead of 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried it but it's worse. Doing that removes the windows prompt altogether and just goes straight to the page.